# Delete related hasManyThrough models

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, relational-database

I have a some models related to eachother like this:

```
Order
  - hasMany(CartItem)
  - hasManyThrough(Product, CartItem)

CartItem
  - belongsTo(Order)
  - hasOne(Product)

Product
  - belongsTo(CartItem)
```

All of the relationships are verified to be working by calling both the dynamic property and the method form (e.g. `$order->products` and `$order->products()` for an Order model)

Now I'd like to delete all products related to a specific order, so I tried this (with order ID = 3):

```
Order::find(3)->products()->delete()
```

However this isn't working. For one reason or the other I get the error message stating the joining column could not be found:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cart_items.order_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: delete from `products` where `cart_items`.`order_id` = 3)
```

The raw SQL output (using `toSql()`) does however include the join...

Anyone knows what's wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Query Builder delete method() works a bit defferently to other methods, thus it mutates the query and there is no join - it simply takes 'wheres' and ommits other parts of the builder.
That being said to achieve what you want use one of these:

```
// This will run delete query for every product
Order::find(3)->products->each(function ($product) {
   $product->delete();
});


// This will run only single query for all of them, which is obviously faster
$productsIds = Order::find(3)->products->modelKeys();
Product::whereIn('id', $productsIds)->delete();
```

Mind that both methods remove rows from the DB but don't remove models from the Collection:

```
$order = Order::find(3);
// run deletes
$order->products; // Collection still contains all the models!
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason for the delete() method to behave differently? Anyhow, thanks a lot. I'll go with the single query method.

Comment: Basically because you'd rather not delete from joined tables, at least in MySQL it's incorrect syntax for delete().

Comment: Is `modelKeys()` a real method? Or just an example? How would you delete only the order `id=3` from the `orders` table and the order's ids in relational table `order_product` but **not** the products (`products`)?

Comment: @pathros why don't you try? https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php#L92  . For the other part - `$order = Order::find(3); $order->products()->sync([]); $order->delete()`

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Wypas! `$productsIds = Order::find(3)->products->modelKeys();` did the trick! Dziękuję bardzo!